# Handling character device drivers written in c using standalone c++ programs

Tags: c++, c, linux

I'm working on a project based on Linux character device drivers and I'm new to implementing device drivers. I have used file file_operations structure and defined my own functions on it as mentioned below.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#define  DEVICE_NAME "char_Driver"
#define  CLASS_NAME  "chrDev"

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int    majorNumber;
static char   message[128] = {0};
static int    numberOpens = 0;
static struct class*  charClass  = NULL;
static struct device* charDevice = NULL;

static int     dev_open(struct inode *, struct file *);
static int     dev_release(struct inode *, struct file *);
static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);

static struct file_operations fops =
{
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = dev_open,
    .read = dev_read,
    .write = dev_write,
    .release = dev_release,
};

static int __init char_init(void){
   printk(KERN_INFO "Char_Driver: Initializing the CharDriver LKM\n");
   majorNumber = register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &fops);
   printk(KERN_INFO "char_Driver: registered correctly with major number %d\n", majorNumber);
   charClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, CLASS_NAME);
   charDevice = device_create(charClass, NULL, MKDEV(majorNumber, 0), NULL, DEVICE_NAME);
   return 0;
}

static void __exit char_exit(void){
   device_destroy(charClass, MKDEV(majorNumber, 0));
   class_unregister(charClass);
   class_destroy(charClass);
   unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, DEVICE_NAME);
   printk(KERN_INFO "Char_Driver: LKM Unloaded!\n");
}

static int dev_open(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep){
   numberOpens++;
   printk(KERN_INFO "Char_Driver: Device has been opened %d times\n", numberOpens);
   return 0;
}

ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filep, char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset){
    size_t ret = copy_to_user(buffer, message, len);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Char_Driver: Sent %zu characters to the user\n", len);
    return ret;
}

ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filep, const char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset){
    size_t ret = copy_from_user(message,buffer,len);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Char_Driver: Received %zu characters from the user\n", len);
    return ret;
}

static int dev_release(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep){
   printk(KERN_INFO "Char_Driver: Device successfully closed\n");
   return 0;
}

module_init(char_init);
module_exit(char_exit);
```

And I'm creating a character device file named "char_driver" in /dev directory automatically when kernel module loading.

My problem is when I use a c program to write and read from the device file its working perfectly. But when I use following C++ program to access that device driver same thing happens. Kernel is logging "Char_Driver: Received 5 characters from the user" message infinitely.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

static fstream dev_file;

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 128
static char receive[BUFFER_LENGTH];
int main(){
    int ret;
    char stringToSend[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    cout << "Starting device test code example...\n";
    dev_file.open("/dev/char_Driver", ios::out);
    if (!dev_file){
        cout << "Failed to open the device...\n";
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "Type in a short string to send to the kernel module:\n";
    cin >> stringToSend;
    cout << "Writing message to the device [" << stringToSend << "]\n";

    dev_file.write(stringToSend, strlen(stringToSend));
    dev_file.close();

    cout << "Press ENTER to read back from the device...\n";
    getchar();


    cout << "file closed successfully..\n";
    dev_file.open("/dev/char_Driver", ios::in);

    cout << "Reading from the device...\n";
    dev_file.read(receive, BUFFER_LENGTH);
    if (ret < 0){
        cout << "Failed to read the message from the device.\n";
        return -1;
    }
    printf("The received message is: [%s]\n", receive);
    printf("End of the program\n");
    dev_file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

My expected output for above mentioned c++ program is mentioned below and its perfectly working for normal files(*.txt, *.sh, etc).

```
Starting device test code example...
Type in a short string to send to the kernel module:
test
Writing message to the device [test]
Press ENTER to read back from the device...

file closed successfully..
Reading from the device...
The received message is: [test]
End of the program
```

but the current output is,

```
Starting device test code example...
Type in a short string to send to the kernel module:
test
Writing message to the device [test]
```

and infinite kernel logs.
And one more thing, when I use,

```
echo 'test' >> /dev/char_Driver "
```

command also kernel is logging "Char_Driver: Received 5 characters from the user" infinitely.
Your Help is realy appreciable.

Comment: In your kernel module, what is `message`? Where and how is it defined?

Comment: Whole source code is now available. message is char array with 128 char elements.

Answer (score 2):

From [this `copy_from_user` reference](https://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re257.html):

> Returns number of bytes that could not be copied. On success, **this will be zero**.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

The `dev_write` function should return the number of bytes it "accepted" (or a negative error code), not zero.

In other words, it should return `len` and not `ret`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It worked. I changed both `return ret;` to `return len;` now the problem is buffer overflow happens when it try to read data from kernel space. It always trys to send 8191 bytes to the user space from kernel space. Still I couldn't fine the problem. I Appreciate if you can help on this problem too

Comment: @BLLGGZ27 That's an issue for another question. And then please create a [mcve] of the kernel module, including the definition and possible initialization of all pointers and arrays.

Comment: I've edited my question and now all the source code of the kernel module in the question.

Comment: @BLLGGZ27 It's still an issue for another question, don't ask two different questions in a single post. And don't change a post to ask a different question from what was originally asked. However here's a hint: You say you send 8191 bytes? How do that fit in the array `message`?

Comment: I just wanted to send 128 bytes from kernel space to user space. But I still cant find where this magic number 8191 came from. In kernel module source code in dev_read function I'm trying to copy the message to buffer variable. Both variables are 128 bytes